# How to find the largest and the lowest differences in a column of an Excel table?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a column with a loads of numbers like this:

1. 12
2. 32
3. 43
4. 12
5. 45
6. 31
7. 43
8. 12

Given *difference* being defined as the difference between a row's value and the previous row's value (RowY - RowX), I should calculate the highest and the lowest differences.

In the example data `A2 - A1` is 20, but `A5 - A4` is 33. Therefore `A5 - A4` is the highest difference. The lowest difference is `A4 - A3`, -31.

I can only use one cell and one formula. I could use a formula like this: `=MAX(A2-A1,A3-A2...)`, but I would like a formula that automates the row selections, instead of manually entering every row combination.

Comment: I see, you want the max difference from the previous row. This wasn't very clear from the question (You can see a lot of people assumed you wanted something else), so I'm going to edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula:

```
=MAX(A2:A8-A1:A7)
```

You need to enter it as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use

`Min(A1:An) - Max(A1:An)`  For the lowest difference

and

`Max(A1:An) - Min(A1:An)`  for the largest difference

where An is  your last row (so in your example, A8)

Answer (score 0):

=MAX(A1:A8)-MIN(A1:A8)   But I dont know why do you have shortage of cells in Excel.

Comment: i'm practising for a contest where I'll get more points if I use only one cells.